# Including Ajax/JS to my voting system in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

How do i make it so that it does not refresh the page? instead it will just update the count numbers? Any help would be appreciated!

Stories controller:

```
def like
  like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, story: @story)
  if like.valid?
    flash[:success] = "Your selection was succesful"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:danger] = "You can only like/dislike a story once"
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: true), :method => :put, :remote => true  do %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i><%= story.thumbs_up_total %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: false), :method => :put, :remote => true  do %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i><%= story.thumbs_down_total %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Story.rb model:

```
def thumbs_up_total
  self.likes.where(like: true).size
end

def thumbs_down_total
  self.likes.where(like: false).size
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller should `respond_to` the `js` "format", as described in [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Instead of `redirect_to :back`, respond with a meaningful status code, for example 201 for success (when a new resource has been created) or 400 for a bad request.

See [RFC 2616, section 10 - Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Then, in your JS, handle the `ajax:success` event. This is also described in [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example:
First change your StoriesController as follow:

```
def like
  @like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, story: @story)
  if @like.valid?
    respond_to do|format|
     format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do|format|
     format.js {render status: 403, js: "alert('You can only like/dislike a story once'"}
    end
  end
end
```

And create a file called like.js.erb within your stories view directory with following content.

```
<% if @like.like %>
 var $element = $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-up");
<% else %>
 var $element = $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-down");
<% end %>
 var oldCount = parseIn($element.text());
 $element.text(oldCount + 1);
```

With the examples aside, you should at least [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) in order to be able to use ajax effectively in rails. It's not that difficult.

Comment: Hi, I think it's firing the javascript but when I look at the index.html.erb page, the number for likes does not go up. but only after i hit refresh, the like will go up.. any help would be appreciated. thanks. @dreamingblackcat

Comment: @SeungHong I forgot the "." s in jquery selector. Just updated the answer. Please try with it again.